# Holo Light with Dark Actionbar showing Holo Dark copy and paste icons

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

so I have an app that is Holo Light with Dark Actionbar and whenever I go to copy and paste something in an EditText, the icons are white so you can't see them. A screenshot is located below. Is there any way to remedy this? Thanks![image: A screenshot of the bug]

Comment: Are you sure that you use the activity context? Using the app context accidentially can have effects like that since the app context does not use / know about the theme.

Comment: Where should I be using the activity context as opposed to the application context? Sorry I'm slightly confused.

Comment: If you use the app context while constructing the ui (implicitly or explicitly using `LayoutInflater`, `Resources`, ...) you get a broken theme. If you use the activity context (`this` inside `Activity` / `.getActivity()` inside `Fragment`) everything should be fine. It's just a guess that you could be using the wrong context.

Comment: Are you talking about when I construct the UI from within onCreate? Once again, horribly confused. Sorry.

Comment: Yes exactly. If you have no `getApplicationContext()` in your app, forget what I said :)

Comment: I do have several getApplicationContext()s, but none have anything to do with layout inflation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually set the theme again in the onCreateDialog method. It is a bug in the framework but this workaround works for the time being:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746561/1508506

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme and I think it's a bug. I tried to change the background in my style with the following (you can get the drawables from http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/):

```
<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="Theme.MyThemeLightBase" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top</item>
</style>
```

And with this:

```
<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="Theme.MyThemeLightBase" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/my_action_mode_style</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/my_action_mode_style</item>
</style>
<style name="my_action_mode_style" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionMode.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/cab_background_top</item>
</style>
```

But none of this solutions appears to work (please let me know if you finally get to change the background) so I decided to let the white background and just change the icons:

```
<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="Theme.MyThemeLight" parent="Theme.MyThemeLightBase">
    <item name="actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_selectall_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_selectall_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_cut_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_cut_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_paste_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_paste_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

Note: You need to specify a styles.xml file in values, values-v11 and values-v14 because some attributes are not necesary added with or without the 'android' preffix. Check the documentation for API level: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionModeCopyDrawable