# Invisible ActionMode item icons in Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme

When using `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` (or `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, doesn't make  a difference), the ActionMode (or "contextual ActionBar") that appears for example when selecting text, is by default styled the same way as in the standard dark theme, that is dark blue with light action icons.

However, when you try to select a text in a Dialog (which is light-styled in this theme, in contrast to the black ActionBar), an ActionMode styled as in the Light theme (white background) appears instead. The problem is, that its action icons are not dark as they should be, but light, making them effectively invisible.

[image]

This seems as if the background was taken from the light theme (because of the light dialog), but the icons were taken from the dark theme. Is this a bug in the `Light.DarkActionBar` theme? Can I do something about it?

Comment: I don't find a solution for this situation, it seems AlertDialog's actionbar theme can only the same as itself. But a workaround is use another DialogFragment for showing the content for the AlertDailog, in this way we can have a Light.DarkActionBar actionmode without problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was fighting with the same issue since last two days. Finally I came up with a workaround!

I am using a `DialogFragment` with an `AlertDialog` object. In the `onCreateDialog()` method, all we have to do is get the context of the parent activity and set its theme again to `Theme.Light`.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //get the parent activity context and set it's theme again.
    Context ctx = getActivity();
    ctx.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null, false);
    builder.setView(view);

    //your other code for the dialog
    //

    return builder.create();
```

Now the icons in the Contextual ActionBar of the `EditText` have the right color.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! Only one thing, you probably wanted to say  _set it's theme to Theme.Light_ - as in the code snippet.

Comment: Oh yes, I edited my answer, but you can set the theme to DarkActionBar to get the dark blue CAB. :)

Comment: Light.DarkActionBar doesn't work for me, the icons are white on white background as above. Only Light theme fixes the problem.

Comment: This is a bad answer for 2 reasons: first it uses a native API11 style, which will not be compatible if using ActionBarSherlock or ActionBarCompat. Second it doesn't change just the dialog theme: it also changes the activity theme so you need to take care of setting your theme back when the dialog is closed.

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me, and I dindn't get any problems with corrupting activity theme

Answer (score 2):

Forcing `setTheme` on the current context is not a good idea, as it corrupts the theme. To solve that you can use [`ContextThemeWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html).

```
Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the icons are still hidden. Tested in Nexus 7 4.4.2.

Comment: Verified, does not work on my 4.4.4 CyanogenMod either.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem. 
I use custom theme inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. In my theme I overrided `actionModeTheme` item by my custom style item. But I faced problem as your problem.
To solve this problem just override `android:alertDialogTheme` item in your custom theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppBaseTheme</item>
        ...
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme">
        ...
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
        ...
</style>
<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionMode">
            ...
            <item name="android:background">@color/gray</item>
            ...
</style>
```

Note, it works since api 11 level.

Comment: didn't help. Icons are still hidden. OS 4.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

App theme is inherited from ***android:Theme.Light***, and there is no dedicated theme for AlertDialog, so that the ActionMode items are somehow invisible.

---

Solution:

**1. Create a dedicated theme for AlertDialog;**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

Note: the most important line which makes the magic is `<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>`

**2. Use the dedicated theme when building an AlertDialog.**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
```

Please have a look at the screenshot which shows before and after applying the theme.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your theme:

```
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_cut_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_paste_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_selectall_holo_light</item>
```

And then add the necessary drawable resources to your project which can be found here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

Comment: This is the only solution that helped me

Answer (score 0):

I tried abovementioned solutions, the only one that worked for me (I have app targeted for API 7, with AppCompat 21.0.3) is to set the dialog style to R.style.Theme_AppCompat. Yes, the stupid dialog is now black. This issue is also present in AppCompat 22.

```
    final Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
    contents = ((LayoutInflater) themedContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.tag_editor, null);
    builder.setView(contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with application I'm maintaining
The solution was very simple - I just had to change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to latest

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use the ActionBar's context to create the AlertDialog:

```
Context themedContext = getActivity().getActionBar().getThemedContext();
```

Or using ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarCompat:

```
Context themedContext = getActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
```

Then create the AlertDialog using this themed context:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
```

Comment: this will make the alertDialog using darkTheme, not the lightTheme

Comment: Does not work for me, does nothing on my Android 4.4.4, Cyanogenmod

Comment: @henry74918 this will make your dialog consistent with your activity's theme. If you want something custom/different you should read the other answers that force a theme.