# Buttons Not Displayed on Copy/Paste Action Bar Associated With A TextView in Dialog

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview

Sadly, I can only test on my Samsung N7000 Note phone with Android 4.1.2 as it is my only device. My app puts up a dialog constructed as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// Set an TextView view to get user input
final TextView input = new TextView(this);
input.setTextIsSelectable(true);
input.setText(sb.toString());
alert.setView(input);
alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
      {
        // do something here
      }
    });

alert.show();
```

This puts up the dialog as expected. However, as shown here, [image: attached screen shot] when I try to select text shown in the TextView the copy/paste action bar is shown but no buttons for copy, select all, etc are shown in the action bar. I note that I can touch the upper right, see a button briefly, and then see a message saying copied to clipboard. I can then go elsewhere and paste the data. So the functionality is there, it is just not being shown to the user.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: u need to write code for copy

Comment: Can you please be a bit more explicit? It seems that everything is working except that the buttons are not being rendered properly. They are there and if you touch them the show up for a brief time and their indicated functions do get executed. So if there is some code I need to write to get the buttons to render properly, please let me know more specifically what you think I need to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ActionbarSherlock` by any chance? It seems to be a bug in the framework, the workaround for which is to manually set the theme again, preferably in the `onCreateDialog` method.

#### See this: **[Invisible ActionMode item icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746561/1533054)**

---

[image: Invisible Actionbar Buttons]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I am not using ActionbarSherlock. To the best of my knowledge, the action bar I am talking about is provided by Android 4.1.2 itself or possibly something added to Android by Samsung for my Note N7000 (which I doubt). It does look like the referenced posting has similar problems to those I am experiencing. I tried this that I saw in that posting: Context themedContext = getActivity().getActionBar().getThemedContext(); AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext); but it produced an unreadable dialog and did not seem to fix the actionbar.